# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined: event.target variable adding class to classname

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
    var button = $(event.target);
    var videoElement = button.parents(".video-row").find("iframe");
    src = videoElement.attr("src");
    title = videoElement.attr("title");
    description = videoElement.attr("description");
    ...
    button.classList.add("green-button");  //error here
```

Which gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

It seems there's something wrong with `button` variable. How do I fix it?

Comment: Is button is a single selector or an array. Can you console and check ?

Comment: @QubaishBhatti It says `at HTMLDivElement`, is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `button` using jQuery (`$`) but then calling `.classList` as if `button` was a native DOM element. Which it's not, it's an instance of jQuery. You need to use the `.addClass()` jQuery method:

```js
button.addClass("green-button");
```

Or, if you wanted to use `.classList`, you could do something like this:

```js
button[0].classList.add('green-button')
```

The `[0]` gets the actual DOM element from the jQuery instance.

Comment: you can use classList and then add method to add class with jquery.

Comment: @QubaishBhatti In the current implementation, `button` is an instance of jQuery. OP would have to get the actual DOM element in order to use `classList`

Answer (score 0):

The error is there because `button` is null. After the line where you define `button`, wrap everything in the conditional check

```
var button = $(event.target);
if (button != null) {
    var videoElement = button.parents(".video-row").find("iframe");
    src = videoElement.attr("src");
    title = videoElement.attr("title");
    description = videoElement.attr("description");
    
    ....
}
```